# Using glob to find duplicate filenames with the same number in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I am currently writing a script that cycles through all the files in a folder and renames them according to a naming convention.

What I would like to achieve is the following; if the script finds 2 files that have the same number in the filename (e.g. '101 test' and '101 real') it will move those two files to a different folder named 'duplicates'.

My original plan was to use glob to cycle through all the files in the folder and add every file containing a certain number to a list. The list would then be checked in length, and if the length exceeded 1 (i.e. there are 2 files with the same number), then the files would be located to this 'duplicates' folder. However for some reason this does not work.

Here is my code, I was hoping someone with more experience than me can give me some insight into how to achieve my goal, Thanks!:

```
app = askdirectory(parent=root)




for x in range(804):
    listofnames = []
    real = os.path.join(app, '*{}*').format(x)
    for name in glob.glob(real):
        listofnames.append(name)
        y = len(listofnames)
        if y > 1:
            for names in listofnames:
                path = os.path.join(app, names)
                shutil.move(path,app + "/Duplicates")
```

Comment: One alternative suggestion to using a list is to create a dictionary that maps the number to the number of times it occurs {number:times occurred}. Then you can just search the times occurred for values greater than 1.

Comment: Hi @pomegranate, thanks for the response, yes that sounds good I will look into how to do that. However in terms of my actual method to find out add duplicates to a list/dictionary, do you think my code should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to collect filenames with numbers in a structure like this:

```
numbers = {
     101: ['101 test', '101 real'],
     93: ['hugo, 93']
}
```

and if a list in this dict is longer than one do the move.

```
import re, os
from collections import defaultdict

app = askdirectory(parent=root)
# a magic dict
numbers = defaultdict(list)

# list all files in this dir
for filename in os.listdir(app):
    # \d+ means a decimal number of any length
    match = re.search('\d+', filename)

    if match is None:
        # no digits found
        continue

    #extract the number
    number = int(match.group())

    # defaultdict magic
    numbers[number].append(filename)

for number, filenames in numbers.items():
    if len(filenames) < 2:
        # not a dupe
        continue
    for filename in filenames:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(app, filename),
                    os.path.join(app, "Duplicates"))
```

`defaultdict` magic is just a short hand for the following code:

```
    if number not in numbers:
        numbers.append(list())
    numbers[number] = filename
```

Comment: Hi @robyschek, thanks for the answer much appreciated! I'm not too familiar with python so I don't fully understand what do you mean when you say that 'defaultdict' is simply shorthand, how do I implement that into my script? do I have to define it as a separate function? Thanks!

Comment: @Ruthus99 `defaultdict`  is already implemented in `collections` module and is imported from there in the header of my first snippet.
I could use a plain dict as well: `numbers = {}` and the code from the second snippet. Eg one magic line replaces three lines.
I added the second snippet just to clarify what that line do.
defaultdict  is already implemented in `collections` module and is imported from there in the header of the first snippet. You can use as well a plain dict: `numbers = {}` and the code from the second snippet. Eg one magic line  replaced with three line.

Comment: Hi @robyschek, ok that makes sense I didn't see the import at the top, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @robyschek, finally just tried your code as I've been busy, but i'M running into some sort of syntax error. Basically wherever I insert the code, every piece function name or for loop after it triggers an 'incorrect syntax' error when I try to run. I'm using sublime text which highlights incorrect syntax with a bright pink red colour and it does that for certain pieces of code after your part. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: sorry about that I figured the problem, there seemed to be a bracket missing towards the end

Comment: @Ruthus99 The bracket was lost in copy/paste. Sorry for that. Good edit:)